# Setup ssh tunnel from docker container on macos Mojave 10.14

Tags: macos, docker, ssh

I am having trouble setting up an ssh tunnel on my mac machine.  I have no problems setting up the tunnel on my ubuntu box.  This is the command I run

`ssh -nNT -L 172.18.0.1:4000:production-database-url:3306 jump-point`

When I run this on my mac, I get the following error:

```
bind [172.18.0.1]:4000: Can't assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 4000 Could
not request local forwarding.
```

If I run without the bind_address (172.18.0.1), I am able to connect to the database via the tunnel.

If I bind to all interfaces (0.0.0.0), then tunnel is open, however, the connection to the database from inside the docker container does not work.

Answer (score 4):

`172.18.0.1` is the IP of docker's [default bridge network gateway](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network), not your host's IP.
You can run this command to check that.

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
```

> Docker for Mac has [limitations](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds)

- There is no docker0 bridge on macOS (it's in the docker VM host on Mac and on Windows)
- You cannot ping containers (without shaving a bunch of yaks)
- Per-container IP addressing is not possible

Also note that this means the docker run option `--net-host` is not supported on Mac, but maybe that's a good thing

> There is a workaround

- These magic addresses resolve to the host's IP from within a container

  - docker.for.mac.localhost   (deprecated)
  - docker.for.mac.host.internal (deprecated)
  - **host.docker.internal**
- This resolves to the gateway of the host mac

  - gateway.docker.internal

Use the name `host.docker.internal` from within the container just like you would use localhost on the mac directly.

Don't worry about the bind address for the tunnel:

```
ssh -nNT -L 4000:production-database-url:3306 jump-point
```

You didn't mention which database but I take it from the port 3306 that it is MySQL.

To connect using the mysql cli from within a container, via an ssh tunnel on your host, to a remote mysql database server you can run:

`mysql --host host.docker.internal [... other options go here]`